# jQuery click append elements to series of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```js
$('button').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var count = 0;

  if (count < 5) {
    $(".container .column:nth-child(1)").append('<div class="element"></div>');
    count++;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button">Add</button>

<div class="container">
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
</div>
```

When I click the button I want to add 4 elements maximum in each column, one by one. For example if I click the button 6 times, the HTML will look like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
     <div class="element"></div>
     <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
</div>
```

This adds 1 `element` div to the first column, each time I click a button, with a 4 `element` div limit.

How can I do the same for the next columns?

**Bonus Question**

Is it possible to also do the opposite when clicking a button to remove elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can target the `column` div by checking the no of `element`s in it using the `length` property.

Additionally, You don't need `:nth-child(1)` property.

```js
$('.add').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var count = 0;
  if (count < 5) {
    $(".container .column").filter(function() {
        return $(this).children('.element').length < 4;
      }).first()
      .append('<div class="element">e</div>');
    count++;
  }
});

$('.remove').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".container .column .element:last").remove();
});
```

```css
.column {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="add">Add</button>
<button type="button" class="remove">Remove</button>

<div class="container">
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
</div>
```

References:

1. [`.filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)
2. [`.first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/)

Comment: Thank you! That works very well! If I also wanted to remove elements when clicking another button for removing, would I just replace `append()` with `remove()`?

Comment: @CyberJ, I have edit the code snippet and added functionality to remove last element. Check if that suits your need

Comment: Wow that required simple functionality! Works great!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code:

```js
$('button').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var columns = $(".container .column");
  var added = false;

  for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
    if (columns[i].childNodes.length < 4) {
      $(columns[i]).append('<div class="element"></div>');
      added = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (!added) {
    console.log('All columns were filled!');
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.column {
  flex: 1;
}

.element {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button">Add</button>

<div class="container">
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
</div>
```